# ASP.NET Core MVC : bootstrap modal not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have been following a tutorial to use bootstrap modals in a CRUD application but I can't get the modal to show.

This is the button calling the jQuery:

```html
<a onclick="CreateOrganization('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Organizations",null,Context.Request.Scheme)','New Organization')" class="btn btn-success text-white"><i class="fas fa-random"></i> New Organization</a>
```

This is the jQuery function which is at the bottom of the same page as the Create Organization button:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript"
src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" > < /script> <
  script type = "text/javascript" >
  CreateOrganization = (url, title) => {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      data: {
        'id': null
      },
      success: function(res) {
        $("#formModal").find(".modal-body").html(res);
        $("#formModal").find(".modal-title").html(res);
        $("#formModal").modal('show');
      },
      failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
      },
      error: function(response) {
        alert("error");
      }
    })
  }; <
/script>
```

The modal is in the _Layout page:

```html
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="formModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" id="formModal">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the AddOrEdit Action Method in the Controller:

```html
public async Task <IActionResult> AddOrEdit(int id = 0)
  { 
    if (id == 0) 
      return View(new Organization()); 
    else 
    { 
      var org = await _context.Organizations.FindAsync(id); 
      if (org == null) 
        { 
         return NotFound(); 
        } 
         return View(org); 
    }
   }
```

When I place an alert() in the jQuery I get the correct url being passed from the button and if I put a break in the AddOrEdit Action method in the controller I does hit the break so the jQuery function appears to be working as expected.  If I place an alert inside the success portion of the ajax{} it hits that so even jQuery seems to be happy.  However, the modal doesn't show.  Can someone please show me where I am going wrong?

Edited Test

Comment: Are you getting any error on brower console? does the request reach to your backend controller?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron It does reach the controller.  No error on the browser.

Comment: Hello did you tried the solution provided? Let me know if you still need any further assistance?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron  Your response did not address the question.

Comment: I found issue on modal script therefore, has shown how to display the modal on response. Rest of the stuff as you confirmed working as expected.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron  If you look at the JQuery function in my post it looks nothing like the Script you posted as an answer.  Could you kindly explain how the two are related.  I don't question that your two lines of code will open up a modal as your demo attests but it isn't obvious how I can take what you have written and modify my JQuery Ajax script.  If you can explain that I will mark the question as answered.

Comment: Dear, @Cameron , thanks for your response, would kindly have a look on my upated answer with full explanation which you been asked. Let me know if you need any further explanation. I would love to do that.

Comment: Dear @MdFaridUddinKiron Thank you for your answer although I managed to find a non jquery method to achieve the same thing which to be honest is much less complicated.  I was trying to use AJAX/jQuery because I couldn't find another way but now I have and I'm sticking to it.  I haven't been able to test your answer but should I go ahead and mark it as correct?  I don't want to break any forum rules.

Comment: You can test , if it doesn't work then absolutely no need to accept. And It will work I can assure, I have therefore, given the implementation sample along with complete output. You can have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

> Could you kindly explain how the two are related. I don't question
> that your two lines of code will open up a modal as your demo attests
> but it isn't obvious how I can take what you have written and modify
> my JQuery Ajax script.

Well, as per my investigations, I found ample of issues on the code. Rather explaining those issues, I was intented to show you the easiest way. However, based on your comment, I am explaining now.

**Issue:1: Script Reference Incompatible With Your Ecma 5:**

It means when I have ran your code, I encountered following error:

[image]

Which telling us, `jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js` this version of `jQuery` unaware of `ecma-5` or later. So I have resolved it by replacing version of `jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js`

**Issue:2: Controller Action:**

In your shared code, you have only shared only one `controller`. However, to make it workable your sample needs two `controller action`. Because, One action need for displaying your view. As your are calling a `GET` operation where you are `explecting data from server` therefore, that controller should return `json data` `instead of view` for instance: `return Ok(org);` Not `return View(org);`

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEdit(int id = 0)
        {
            if (id == 0)
                return View(new Users());
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    var org = await _context.Organizations.FindAsync(id);
                    if (org == null)
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    return Ok(org); ;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw;
                }
               
               
            }
        }

        public IActionResult AddOrEditView()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

**Issue:3: Incorrect Bindings Or Object Parsing:**

In your `GET` method on `success: function(res)` your are binding `response` directly to `html` which cannot be displayed as its getting it as `object order` which is a `json data object` as you can see below:

[image]

```
$("#formModal").find(".modal-body").html(res);
$("#formModal").find(".modal-title").html(res);
```

Therefore, you should bind it with explicit declaration as below:

```
$("#formModal").find(".modal-body").html(res.skills);
$("#formModal").find(".modal-title").html(res.developerName);
```

**Note:** I am defining it as per my object as `res.skills` you could replace as per yours.

**Final: Output**

[image]

**Code:**

```cs
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="formModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" id="formModal">
                <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
               
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a onclick="CreateOrganization('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Todo",null,Context.Request.Scheme)','New Organization')" class="btn btn-success text-white"><i class="fas fa-random"></i> New Organization</a>
@*
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>*@
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   
    CreateOrganization = (url, title) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: {
                'id': 1
            },
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                $("#formModal").find(".modal-body").html(res.skills);
                $("#formModal").find(".modal-title").html(res.developerName);
                $("#formModal").modal('show');
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                alert("error");
            }
        })
    };
</script>
```

**Previous Sample Example:**

I have checked your code and found issue on your `script` and modal `HTML` as well. Please try following code snippet which works as expected.

**Model**

```cs
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="formModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" id="formModal">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Tesing Modal Error</h5>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
             
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```cs
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   
    $(document).ready(function () {
       
        $(function () {
            $('#formModal').modal('show');
        });

    });
   
</script>
```

**Output**

[image]

**Note:** I have tried to troubleshoot your modal display issue. So data realted to controller response has not varified or tested.

Comment: @Kiron  I can't get it to work.  I have been trying for the last 4 hours but for some reason there's a problem. I have edited the post so you can see the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, However, your issue is in two places as explained earlier. First of all could you please include what `Organizations` containing? Now come to the issue, replace to `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` instead of `jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js`, another problem is here `find(".modal-body").html(res)` it will not work, it should be like `find(".modal-body").html(res.skills)`. Means, the property of your `Organizations` class is returning. Modify above snippet and it will work as expected.

Comment: Kiron.  Sorry, but I was unable to edit the post because the edit queue is full apparently.  But I did change to 3.2.1 and used res.something instead of just res but it still doesn't work.  I'm getting an error in the ajax part of the function.

Comment: Which error you are getting? You could ask new question with the error, I would have a look on that as well. However, I have posted the solution in a way it should work by simply copy and paste. No worries please share the error details.

Comment: Additonally, Edit is also working therefore, it would be wise to post new question with the error you are getting.

Comment: Kiron.  Unfortunately I can't share the error details.  It is just the alert message (I think) which says error and it stays open for less than a millisecond.  It's almost impossible to see if you''re not paying attention.  Someone else helped me though and told me to use a button instead of the <a> tag.  I didn't believe him at first but for some weird reason it did end up opening the modal.  Now my problem is accessing the data in the modal but I will post another question for that.

Comment: So its pointing issue on your side, The solution povided has no issue, and working as expected right?

Comment: Kiron I can't say if the solution worked because as you read a few moments ago I am getting an error message.  I have posted a new question so I think we should just drop this thread.

Comment: No worries, I am ready to work on this further, just let me know when you need any further assistance on this.